# NetLogo substitute for breed

Tags: netlogo

I was wondering whether there is a substitute for the breed function in Net Logo?

I looked for a substitute in the dictionary but all I found was `globals` and I don't think that fully covers what the breed function can do. If there is a substitute, what is it?

Comment: What do you mean by a substitute? What's wrong with `breed` itself?

Comment: What do you want to do that breed can't?

Comment: marijn, are you sure that "substitute" is the right word for what you are asking about?

Comment: @Bryan Head, substitute as is using something else for breed. This was a question on an exam I recently had. They asked me whether breed can be removed from a model and be replaced with another command without changing the function of the model, so i'm pretty sure substitute(s) is the right word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [`turtle-set`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtle-set)?  This allows you to create an agentset from an arbitrary collection of turtles.